# Decrypted file is still encrypted

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I have been working on this for a few hours now, First I would like to explain what I'm trying to do; Encrypt / Decrypt Files in C using OpenSSL. The problem seems to be arising in decryption method. Documentation is scarce and I have pieced this together along with referring back to books etc.

When the code is ran, there are no issues in output. When opening the intended decrypted file its in fact still encrypted...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

/*=========================================================================|
Encryption Method below, This Will Take The File And Use The Keys And IV  
To Encrypt The Data/File. We Use Long Here Because Int Only Is Good For <2GB
Data Size And Will Get ERRORS If File Is Larger Than >= 2GB Which Is As Common
as gold-diggers. */

void encrypt_process()
{
    unsigned char key[] = "badidea";
    unsigned char vec[] = "again";

    FILE *Input_File;
    FILE *Output_file;
    Input_File =fopen("french.txt", "rb");
    Output_file = fopen("ult.txt", "wb");//File to be written; cipher text
    fseek(Input_File, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(Input_File); // use long as the file if >2GB will blow past int
    printf("length of the file is : %lu", len);

    unsigned long outLen1 = 0;
    unsigned long outLen2 = 0;
    unsigned char *indata = malloc(len);
    unsigned char *outdata = malloc(len);

    fread(indata,sizeof(char),len, Input_File);//Read Entire File

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*\
    <|||    Set Up Encryption As Defined in OPENSSH using their syntax etc.>>>
    *-----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    //initiating cipher
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;

    EVP_EncryptInit(&ctx,EVP_aes_128_cbc(),key,vec);
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx,outdata,&outLen1,indata,len);

    EVP_EncryptFinal(&ctx,outdata + outLen1,&outLen2);
    fwrite(outdata,sizeof(char),outLen1 + outLen2,Output_file);

    fclose(Input_File); // free all pointers and clean up
    fclose(Output_file);

    Input_File = NULL;
    printf("\n Encryption Process Complete");
}

/*=========================================================================|
Decryption Method below, This Will Take The File And Use The Keys And IV
To Decrypt The Data/File. We Use Long Here Because Int Only Is Good For <= 2GB
Data Size And Will Get ERRORS If File Is Larger Than 2GB Which Is As Common
as gold-diggers */

void decrypt_process()
{
    unsigned char key[] = "badidea";
    unsigned char vec[] = "again";

    FILE *Input_File;
    FILE *Output_file;
    Input_File =fopen("ult.txt", "rb");
    Output_file = fopen("claro.txt", "wb");
    fseek(Input_File, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(Input_File); // use long as the file if >2GB will blow past int
    printf("length of the file is : %lu", len); //xcode underlines this?

    unsigned long outLen1 = 0;
    unsigned long outLen2 = 0;
    unsigned char *indata = malloc(len);
    unsigned char *outdata = malloc(len);

    fread(indata,sizeof(char),len, Input_File);//Read Entire File

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*\
    <|||    Set Up Decryption As Defined in OPENSSH using their syntax etc.>>>
    *-----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    //initiating decrypt
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;

    EVP_DecryptInit(&ctx,EVP_aes_128_cbc(),key,vec);
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx,outdata,&outLen1,indata,len);
    EVP_DecryptFinal(&ctx,outdata + outLen1,&outLen2);
    fwrite(outdata,sizeof(char),outLen1 + outLen2,Output_file);

    fclose(Input_File); // free all pointers and clean up
    fclose(Output_file);
    Input_File = NULL;

    printf("\n Decryption Process Complete");
}

// main entry point
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{            
    char option[5]; //local buffer to get input
    printf("\n **********Welcome To Encryption And Decryption Services!");
    printf("****** \n Type e for ecryption or d for decryption (more options later) ");

    scanf("%s", option); // should use fgets

    if(strcmp(option, "e")== 0){
        printf("*********  Encryption Process Initiated \n What File Do You Want To Encrypt? Complete Path Needed");

        encrypt_process(); // our encryption method
    }
    else if(strcmp(option,"d")== 0){
        printf("*********  Decryption Process Initiated");
        decrypt_process();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you follow this https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption or some thing else

Comment: Followed bits and pieces of different documentation until I pieced it together .. When the encryption worked I got excited and made a reverse method attempting the decryption but failed, I really don't understand where I'm going wrong I don't have any error output to go off of either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first main problem here is that you're not doing any error checking.  So when things go wrong you have no way of knowing.

All I/O routines (`fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `fseek`) should be checked for errors with the error code printed using `perror`.

Similarly, all OpenSSL functions should be checked for errors as well.  The `ERR_error_string` and `ERR_get_error` functions will tell you what your errors are.  You'll need to call `ERR_load_crypto_strings` at the start of your program to load the error strings.

With that being said, there are two things causing your problems.

First, when you read from the input file (in both your encrypt and decrypt routines), you're already at the end of the file, so you don't read anything.  You need to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file before reading.

```
    fseek(Input_File, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(indata,sizeof(char),len, Input_File);//Read Entire File
```

The other problem is the size of your key and IV:

```
    unsigned char key[] = "badidea";
    unsigned char vec[] = "again";
```

Because no explicit size is given for these arrays, there are as large as their initializers, 8 and 6 bytes respectively in this case (one for each character in the string plus one for the nul terminating byte).  AES-128 requires 32 bytes for the key and 16 bytes for the IV.  Because these arrays are not large enough, the encrypt/decrypt routines read past the end of these arrays, resulting in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Give these arrays an explicit size:

```
    unsigned char key[32] = "badidea";
    unsigned char vec[16] = "again";
```

Because each of these variables has an initializer, any remaining bytes not explicitly initialized are set to 0.

Comment: Thanks, I will implement this now and get back to you.

Comment: also free(members); what is members value ?

Comment: Apologies, I had some other code in there as well commented out but deleted the code for this post as it was non-related in this context. There were just VARS in a struct before in another version of testing that produced the same errors and results.

Comment: Holy Macro, it works! thank you. Problem is what you described so fseek(Input_File, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long len = ftell(Input_File);
    fseek(Input_File, 0, SEEK_SET);
    
    printf("length of the file is : %lu", len); 
was the missing piece... Without bugging too much Im not to clear on the key and iv why do we have to load them [32] and [16] in this case? "Because each of these variables has an initializer, any remaining bytes not explicitly initialized are set to 0."